# Send HTML from C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html

Hi i want to append html in my c#
here is my code for that

```
        rework = "<label class=\"assignmentIcon\" title=\"tinyc Count    "+tinykCount+"\"BigCount:"+reworkCount+">" + sampleCount + "</label>";
```

And this code i am putting in jquery data tabl.So,it is working absolutely fine but in the tooltip its just showing "tinyc Count" and its value
but i also want to show BigCount along with its value in a new line in tool tip bu i am unable to append it 
here

```
tinykCount,reworkCount
```

are variable which i am passing from C#,i can also do this with jquery but i dont want to make additional call to it

Comment: Check what's title value returning to client in html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In Controller:

```
string rework = "<label class=\"assignmentIcon\" title=\"tinyc Count:" + tinykCount + "\n BigCount:" + reworkCount + "\">" + sampleCount + "</label>";
```

You can pass this to `View` using `ViewBag` from Controller

```
 ViewBag.t = rework;
```

In View:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.t)
```